# Редирект id на pdo

Tags: php

Всем привет. У меня есть 3 textarea и input. При клике на input, все данные с textarea переходят в бд. А также есть файл code.php . Также есть функция $_GET['ID']. При переходе, например на code.php?ID=1, показывается все данные у textarea связанные с этой id. Как мне сделать, чтобы при клике на input меня редиректило на то id, которое сохранается в бд. Пробовал вот так

```
if($singleview){
    foreach($singleview as $rows){ 
        header('Location: code.php?ID='.$rows['id'].'');
    }
}
```

, но не работает, а также не работает через $id=$_GET['ID'];

```
<?php
include 'db/database.php';
if (isset($_GET['ID'])){

    $id=$_GET['ID'];
        $sql="select * from field where ID=:ID order by id desc";
        $data= $db->prepare($sql);
        $data->execute(array(':ID' => $id));
    $singleview =$data->fetchAll();
        }


        if($singleview){
            foreach($singleview as $rows){ 
                $GLOBALS['id_link'] = 'as';
            }
        }

if(isset($_POST['add-post'])) {


    // Get data from FROM
    $html_field = $_POST['html_field'];
    $css_field = $_POST['css_field'];
    $js_field = $_POST['js_field'];

try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO field (html_field, css_field, js_field) VALUES (:html_field, :css_field, :js_field)');
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':html_field' => $html_field,
        ':css_field' => $css_field,
        ':js_field' => $js_field
        ));

        if (isset($_GET['ID'])){

            $id=$_GET['ID'];
        header('Location: code.php?ID='.$id.'');
        }

    exit;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}




}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test coder</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
        <div class="display-none">
        <textarea name="html_field" class="html_field"></textarea> 
         <textarea name="css_field" class="css_field"></textarea> <br>
         <textarea name="js_field" class="js_field"></textarea> <br>
         </div>
        <input type="submit" name="add-post" class="add-post" value="Добавить статью">
        </form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: В `$_GET['ID']` именно то, что вы получили от клиента. А при insert вы же от клиента id не получали. ID последней вставленной записи http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте начнем по порядку.

1. `$_GET` - это переменная, а не функция.
2. `<form method="post">` это ваша форма, чтобы передать значение в переменную `$_GET`, необходимо указать в `action` `<form action="code.php?id={ваше значение}" method="post">`
3. Но так как у вы добавляете запись в базу, `id` Вам еще не известно. Чтобы получить `id` последней добавленной записи нужно сделать следующее:

---

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO field (html_field, css_field, js_field) VALUES (:html_field, :css_field, :js_field)');
$stmt->execute(
  array(
    ':html_field' => $html_field,
    ':css_field' => $css_field,
    ':js_field' => $js_field
  )
);
$id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

4. После чего можно сделать проверку на полученный `id`. Если все хорошо то произойдет нужный редирект.

---

```
if ($id){
  header("Location: code.php?ID=${id}");
}
```

Comment: Проверка на полученный id не нужна. Проверка без else вообще никогда не нужна.

Comment: @Ипатьев, все что будет описано после условия, можно считать, что это `else`.

Comment: Нельзя. 1. Все что написано после не имеет отношения к проверке. 2. Что бы ни было написано, оно все равно не будет исполнено.  Рекомендую писать в ответах только осмысленный код, это делает ответ полезнее.

Comment: @Ипатьев т.е вы хотите сказать, что всегда, во всех случаях, должна быть ветка `else` ?

Comment: Наоборот. Я хочу сказать, что если у вас нет идей, что написать в else, то не надо писать бессмысленных проверок. Это общее правило. В данном же конкретном случае это вдвойне бессмысленно, поскольку код в else, даже будучи написанным, никогда не будет исполнен.

Comment: @Ипатьев, Расскажи почему в данном случае ветка `else` никогда не будет исполненной?